# Добавление методов расширения linq для своего класса

Tags: c#, linq

Захотелось реализовать методы расширения типа MyClassObj.Select(..)  и т.д. Пытаюсь сделать с помощью реализации интерфейса IEnumerable в своем классе:

```
public class Nums: IEnumerable
{
    private int[] _nums = {3,5,6,10,20,-1,0};
    public Nums()
    {
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return (IEnumerator)GetEnumerator();
    }

    public PeopleEnum GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new ТumsEnum(_nums);
    }
}

public class NumsEnum : IEnumerator 
{
    public int[] _nums;
    int position = -1;

    public NumsEnum(int[] list)
    {
        _nums = list;
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        position++;
        return (position < _nums.Length);
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        position = -1;
    }

    object IEnumerator.Current
    {
        get
        {
            return Current;
        }
    }

    public int Current
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                return _nums[position];
            }
            catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

но при вызове:

```
MyClassObj.Select(..)
```

Компилятор ругается, что класс не содержит данного метода. Хотя (как мне кажется) он должен появиться после реализации интерфейса IEnumerable.  Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы делаете не так две вещи.

Во-первых, вы забыли добавить в файл, где используете этот класс, директиву

```
using System.Linq
```

всё-таки это методы расширения, определенные в другом классе, и без импорта пространства имен  они не заработают.

Во-вторых, вы реализуете не тот интерфейс. У интерфейса IEnumerable нет методов расширения Select. Они есть в его обобщенном варианте IEnumerable<T> (это можно увидеть [тут](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx)), и представляют собой не что иное, как методы из статического класса Enumerable.

И еще - пожалуйста, поправьте ваш код, который вы добросовестно скопировали с [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx), поскольку он у вас даже не компилируется - в  частности, в классе Nums остался конструктор People() из майкрософтовского примера